# O webservice pode definir um uso de memória limite para quem o consulta?

Tags: php, web-service, memória

Estou com problemas com um *webservice* porque faço uma consulta que me retorna 69300 registros e corre tudo bem mas já com 69595 registros ele dá [**erro**](http://developerscg.hospedagemdesites.ws).

A pergunta: O *webservice* pode definir um uso de memória limite para quem o consulta? Estou consumindo 90MB nesta consulta.

O programa que está sendo rodado é estritamente fornecido pelo *webservice* conforme demonstrado abaixo:

```
$array  = array ( 
        'key'       => '8b0dc65f996f98fd178a9defd0efa077',
        'module'    => 'imoveis',
        'method'    => 'busca_fotos',
        'field'     => array (
            'CODIGO'    => 'Codigo',
            'IMAGEM_G'  => 'Foto'
        ),
        # 'limit'   => '69300'
    );

    $client = new SoapClient(null, array (
        'uri' => 'http://soap.imo.bi/',
        'location' => 'http://soap.imo.bi/soap.dll',
        'trace' => 'trace'
    ));

    $res    = $client->get($array);
    $tot    = count($res);

    echo "<pre>";
         print_r($res);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Eu antes tinha entendido que _você_ estava desenvolvendo esse web service. Então você somente está tendo problemas com a grande quantidade de dados retornada por ele, certo?

Comment: E outra coisa, essa key indicada no seu exemplo não é informação confidencial sua?

Comment: Ela pode ser alterada. Em relação ao problema, a grande quantidade de dados retornados esse é o problema.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta básica é bem fácil responder: sim, claro, pode. Qualquer programa pode definir limites que ele desejar. O ideal é que especialmente *webservices* tenha limitações para evitar abusos.

Mas pelo *link* postado parece que o problema ali é outro. Parece que o servidor está atolado. Ironicamente muito provavelmente por não impor limites de uso.

Sem maiores informações é difícil dizer exatamente o que está acontecendo mas é claro que o serviço prestado não foi bem desenvolvido, o que é muito comum. É muito comum o pessoal testar para ver se funciona mas esquecem que o teste mais importante é testar para ver o que  acontece quando não funciona e não deixar acontecer situações catastróficas como a ocorrida no exemplo.

Comment: Com base na **Atualização** da pergunta, é possível se falar em má programação? Poderia ser problema relacionado ao webservice? Nesse servidor só tem esse script, não tem mais nada.

Comment: Eu desconheço o `SoapClient` mas no geral este código não parece ter nenhum problema aparente. Claro que esse retorno criado pelo SOAP pode ser gigantesco. O problema pode estar aí e não no *script*.

Answer (score 3):

O ideal seria você definir um limite de registros retornados consulta (onde você possa ter certeza que não ultrapassará o seu limite de memória) e implementar algum tipo de paginação para que seja possível navegar por todos os resultados sem ter que enviar tudo de uma vez.

Imagine se uma busca no Google retornasse *todos* os resultados de uma vez só.

---

**Atualização:**

Seguindo o [**manual**](http://www.vistasoft.com.br/download/RQV_035%20-%20Integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20dos%20Im%C3%B3veis%20no%20Website%20ver2_rev01.pdf) do web service que você está utilizando:

> Parâmetro: limit
>
> **String**: Pode ser especificado o limite de resultados, podendo ser um valor numérico simples ou paginação. Para paginação, deve-se
> utilizar o formato **x,y**, onde **x** é o número do registro e **y**
> é o limite de registros.

Tudo que você precisa é usar o parâmetro `limit` para paginar os resultados e pegar um pedaço de cada vez. Dessa forma você faz o que tem que fazer com essa "página" de resultados, descarta e parte pra próxima.